# Why is there limited use of Y (Wye) fittings in a refrigeration system?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, hvac, refrigeration

I'm a Mechanical Engineering intern currently working in HVAC and Refrigeration for grocery stores.

I'm looking into ways, with lower energy losses, to encourage equal flow distribution at liquid pipe junctions. I'm wondering if anyone can give me insight as to why there is limited cases of using copper wyes or "Y" junction fittings in refrigeration systems, and why there is only "T" junctions.

I've read somewhere that it has to do with the "Y" design not performing well in high pressure scenarios but I haven't been able to find any other information on the subject.

FYI I'm based in Sydney, Australia. If things are different overseas I'd love to hear your input too!

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: I would imagine it's solely because construction of a wye will cost more than a Tee.